# Winforms .Net Application won't start

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a standard winforms application that runs on most machines. On a 2003 server with .Net 4 (full) installed it doesn't run.

The event viewer shows:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   .NET Runtime
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1026
Date:       4/01/2012
Time:       10:07:37 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   DRACO
Description:
Application: start.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319

Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception 
Info: System.TypeInitializationException
Stack:
   at BootStrap.Program.Main(System.String[])

Event Type: Error
Event Source:   .NET Runtime 4.0 Error Reporting
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1000
Date:       4/01/2012
Time:       10:07:34 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   DRACO
Description:
Faulting application start.exe, version 1.0.4386.17553, stamp 4f0384f3, faulting module     kernel32.dll, version 5.2.3790.4480, stamp 49c51f0a, debug? 0, fault address 0x0000bef7.
```

It fails on the Main() call so I can't trap the errors. How do I tell what the problem is?

Comment: did you try running it under a debugger?

Comment: It's on a production machine, that I would rather not install a development environment onto. I have installed onto another 2003 box and it ran ok.

Comment: @PHemans it's possible to remote debug on production machines without having to install anything.  The remote debugger components are xcopy deployable.  I think you're really in a jam where you'll either need to 1) deploy a modified binary or 2) debug in some way on the target machine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exception is a `TypeInitializationException`.  This is thrown when an exception was generated executing the initializer code for a type.  Basically the static constructor or the initialization of static fields.  Some part of that initialization is throwing an exception which results in a `TypeInitializationException`

The exception information itself will say which type is causing this via the `TypeName` property.

It's hard to say for certain what is causing this problem.  The quickest way to find out would be to start the process under a debugger and set it to break on any thrown exception.  That should immediately lead you to the root cause.

Comment: Problem was the installation routine had missed a new required assembly. The assembly was used with a static member so the app crashed before the main.

Answer (score 8):

The interesting part is the following: `System.TypeInitializationException`

This means that one of the types used in your main method failed to initialize. Usually the static `constructor` is throwing an exception which is caught by the initializer and then re-thrown as inner exception of a `System.TypeInitializationException`. Catch the exception in your main method and show its inner exception or use a debugger.

Comment: How do you catch an exception in the main method if it is failing at BootStrap.Program.Main(System.String[]) ?

Comment: Its failing at the method which means that the exception is thrown while executing an instruction of the function. Thus surrounding the Main-function with a try-catch block should work.

Comment: Sorry, didn't help. I will have to go the route of remote debugging